# How do I find/contact an owner or admin of a Pivotal Tracker Enterprise account where my Project resides?

Tags: pivotaltracker

I would like to add an integration but I have no idea how to contact the owner or any admins.
When I go to https://pivotaltracker.com/accounts I see a userID for the owner (no email) of my Enterprise account, and I see that 4 admins exist but no other information.

Also, neither are hyperlinked or have tooltips.

On the integrations menu/tab it tells me that I need to contact the administrator, but it doesn't tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I reached out to support@pivotaltracker.com and they helped me out. I did not discover a self-service method.